# SNES PPU die photo

Tags: hardware, graphics, chip, snes

The heart of many classic home computers and game consoles was the graphics chip, yet these tend to be less well-documented than the corresponding CPUs. Still, there are die photos of two of the most important graphics chips of the eighties, the VIC-II and the NES PPU.

I have not been able to find a die photo of the SNES PPU. Is there one available?

Comment: The apparent duplicate question is about the NES, not the SNES.

Comment: My mistake.  Nominated for reopening.

Comment: I lack sufficient expertise in the subject to judge the contents, but the images linked from [this forum post about 'decapped' PPUs](http://helmet.kafuka.org/byuubackup2/viewtopic.php@f=10&t=1900.html) look like die photos to me.  For instance: (warning very large image) http://siliconpr0n.org/map/nintendo/s-ppu2-b/single/nintendo_s-ppu2-b_mz_ns20x.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(With thanks to Conspicuous Compiler's comment above)*

The SNES' PPU (or S-PPU) was actually [two chips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Nintendo_Entertainment_System#Video): a pair of 100-pin ICs operating together.

There are die photos of the pair (the [S-PPU1](http://siliconpr0n.org/map/nintendo/s-ppu1/) and [S-PPU2B](http://siliconpr0n.org/map/nintendo/s-ppu2-b/)) hosted on siloconpr0n.org, as 100+Mb JPEGs and a JavaScript-based scroll and zoom interface. I've attached thumbnails of each below:

S-PPU1: [image: S-PPU1]
S-PPU2: [image: S-PPU2B]

The 64KB of SRAM can be seen in the top-left corner of the S-PPU1 (in two 32kbit x 8 chunks), and the 256 × 15 bits of color generator RAM can be seen in the bottom left corner of the S-PPU2.

Comment: Great, thanks! About the proposed identification of the SRAM blocks on each chip, though: 64KB is 128 times as much as 256x15bit, yet the former block looks about the same size as the latter. Should the latter block not be visibly about two orders of magnitude smaller?